# Как сделать так, чтобы нарисовать несколько линий на одном холсте?

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, paintevent, drawline

Программа рисует линию, 
*при попытке нарисовать вторую, первая исчезает*, 
а должна оставаться.

Буду рад, если поможете.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QLineF


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 700, 500)
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.start = QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton:
            self.image.fill(Qt.white)
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.start, event.pos())
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы не очищаете всё между линиями? `self.image.fill(Qt.white)`

Comment: @vp_arth Проблема в том, что если я уберу эту строчку, то линия начнется рисоваться каждую секунду(что мне не нужно)

Comment: Ну, если вы стираете линию, которую хотите оставить, наверное не нужно её стирать?

Comment: @vp_arth Вы можете запустить программу и понять, что без этой строчки кода не будет рисоваться нормальная линия. Я не спорю о том, что это строчка лишняя, вопрос заключается в том, как сделать программу, которая будет спокойно рисовать сразу несколько линий, не стирая их. Я не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: Хм, простите, неправильно понял ваш код. Вы там вообще никаких линий не рисуете)) Только image целиком

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите нарисовать n-линий, вы должны сохранить эту информацию в списке.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QLineF


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 700, 500)
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.start = QPoint()
        
        self.lines = []                                                  # +++

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
        
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))                  # +++
        for i in self.lines:                                             # +++
            painter.drawLine(*i)                                         # +++

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.image.fill(Qt.white)
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.start, event.pos())
            self.update()
            
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                                     # +++
        self.lines.append([self.start, event.pos()])                        # +++
        self.update()                                                       # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как дополнение, лучше сделать оперативный image прозрачным и рисовать его после всех сохранённых объекта. Сейчас это не важно, но когда добавится выбор цвета, станет.

Comment: @vp_arth будет проблема - будем решать :)

Comment: @S. Nick как раз таки насчет цвета. Я добавил цвет и толщину для линии. Но при изменении толщины или цвета для одной линии, меняется сразу и для всех... Можете помочь?

Comment: @r64 выставляйте новый вопрос. Публикуйте пример, опишите что вы хотите сделать и что не получается. Завтра будем посмотреть.

Comment: @r64 зачем вы убрали пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202414/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5#1202414 ? Вы сделали/нашли решение ? Только начал смотреть, а вы его удалили  - почему?

Comment: @S. Nick Думал, что уже никто не ответит, сейчас добавлю обратно

Comment: @r64 никогда не торопитесь, помогаем по мере свободного времени.

Comment: @S. Nick вот ссылка - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202880/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать цикл for, в него засунь код для отображения нужной тебе линии. Создаёшь например 2 цикла for, пихаешь в один код для 1 линии, а во второй цикл - код для 2 линии.