# Выделение и копирование определенной области

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

В инструментах есть выделение прямоугольной области. Оно должно копировать и вствалять выделенную область.

Также у меня не растягивается вставленное фото на полной экран. Помогите пожалуйста

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        instmenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Инстументы")
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")

        brush = QAction("Кисть", self)
        instmenu.addAction(brush)
        brush.triggered.connect(self.setBrush)

        rect = QAction("Прямоугольник", self)
        instmenu.addAction(rect)
        rect.triggered.connect(self.setRectangle)

        photo = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        file.addAction(photo)
        photo.triggered.connect(self.getImage)

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.instrument = 'brush'

        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 8

        self.start_pos = QPointF()
        self.end_pos = QPointF()

        self.brush_points = []

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.transparent)

    def getImage(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "", "",
            "Images(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)"
        )[0]
        if not filename:
            return
        self.image.load(filename)

    def draw(self, canvas):
        painter = QPainter(canvas)
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))

        if self.instrument == 'brush':
            for i in self.brush_points:
                painter.drawPoint(i)

        elif self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, self.brushSize, Qt.DashLine))
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.start_pos, self.end_pos))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.image.rect(), self.image)

        self.draw(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_pos = event.pos()
        self.brush_points.clear()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end_pos = event.pos()
            self.brush_points.append(self.end_pos)

            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.end_pos = event.pos()
        self.brush_points.append(self.end_pos)

        self.draw(self.image)
        self.update()

    def setBrush(self):
        self.instrument = 'brush'

    def setRectangle(self):
        self.instrument = 'rectangle'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я добавил в меню опцию `"Выделить для копирования"` и отметил по тексту изменения, которые внес.

Свое делаете как и делали, я ничего не трогал.

Когда надо вырезать что-нибудь - сделайте клик по меню `"Выделить для копирования"`, затем зажав ЛКМ выделяете участок, отпускаете ЛКМ и все.

Появившееся новое изображение можете перетаскивать как обычное окно.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF

from PIL import ImageGrab                                                  # +++
import numpy as np                                                         # +++
import cv2                                                                 # +++


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, img, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.pixmapImagen = QPixmap(img) 
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmapImagen)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.origin = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.windowPos().toPoint() - self.origin)
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        instmenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Инстументы")
        file = mainMenu.addMenu("Файл")
        brush = QAction("Кисть", self)
        instmenu.addAction(brush)
        brush.triggered.connect(self.setBrush)
        videlenie = QAction("Прямоугольное выделение", self)
        instmenu.addAction(videlenie)
        videlenie.triggered.connect(self.setVid)
        videlenie = QAction("Выделить для копирования", self)        # +++
        instmenu.addAction(videlenie)                                # +++
        videlenie.triggered.connect(self.screenshot)                 # +++
        photo = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        file.addAction(photo)
        photo.triggered.connect(self.getImage)

        self.image_foreground = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.transparent)
        self.image_background = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        self.image_background.fill(Qt.white)

        self.brushColor = Qt.blue         # black
        self.brushSize = 8
        self.instrument = 'brush'
        self.coords = QPointF()

        self.selection = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self) # +++
        self.start = QPointF() 
        self.end = QPointF()        

    def getImage(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Выберите изображение", 
            "",
            "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)"
        )
        if not filename:
            return
        self.image_background.load(filename)
        self.selection.hide()                                # +++

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image_background, self.image_background.rect())
        painter.drawImage(self.image_foreground.rect(), self.image_foreground)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'brush':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            self.coords = event.pos()
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'screenshot':     # +++
            self.start = event.pos() 
            self._start = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'brush':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.coords, event.pos())
            self.coords = event.pos()
            self.update()
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            self.update()
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.instrument == 'screenshot':      # +++
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.selection.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.start, self.end).normalized())
            self.selection.show()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.instrument == 'rectangle':
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, self.brushSize, Qt.DashLine))
            painter.drawRect(QRectF(self.coords, event.pos()))
            self.update()
        elif self.instrument == 'screenshot':                                            # +++
            self._end = event.globalPos()
            self.selection.hide()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(20, self.newLabel)

    def newLabel(self):
        self.selection.hide()
        self.instrument = 'None'
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(
            self._start.x(), 
            self._start.y(), 
            self._end.x(), 
            self._end.y()
        ))
        
        pathImage = 'new_image.png'      # тут будет обрезанное изображение
        img.save(pathImage)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()        

        self.labelImagen = Label(pathImage, self)
        self.labelImagen.resize(self.selection.size())                          
        self.labelImagen.show()

    def setBrush(self):
        self.instrument = 'brush'
        self.selection.hide()

    def setVid(self):
        self.instrument = 'rectangle'
        self.selection.hide()
        
    def screenshot(self):                                                           # +++
        self.instrument = 'screenshot'
        
    def sizeHint(self):                                                             # +++
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 500)    
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):                                                   # +++
        self.image_foreground = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.transparent)
        self.update()
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]